# How can you create an os.environ object with a modified environment, e.g. after loading many different modules with "module load"?

Tags: python, environment-variables, environment-modules

I have a python script that calls an application using `subprocess`. I am calling this application many times, currently I am doing something along the lines of

```
out, err = subprocess.Popen(f"module load {' '.join(my_module_list)} && ./my_binary", stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, shell = True).communicate()
```

to run my program. Ideally I would like to first generate a modified [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) object that already contains all the paths to the modules I am loading, and then pass it to `subprocess.Popen` under the `env` argument. However, since the `printenv` command doesn't output a python dictionary format, I'm not sure how to access all the modifications that `modules load` makes to the environment variables. Is there a good, clean way to create the required modified `os.environ` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to call `python` in the `subprocess` and dump from `os.environ` in it

```py
python -c 'import os; print(os.environ)'
```

Once you know what you're after, you can pass a dict directly to `subprocess`'s `env` arg to set custom environmental vars, which could be something like

```py
custom_env = os.environ.copy()
custom_env["foo"] = "bar"

subprocess.Popen(
    ...
    env=custom_env,
)
```